# Using my computer as MySQL database and access with Xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, mysql

I have developed an app from xamarin.forms (C#) and I want to use my own computer to host a mySQL database. I have forwarded my port on my router as well but the database can only be accessed when my phone(xamarin.forms app) and my computer (MySQL database and server) are conected on the same wifi.

[My Router's Menu (Xplor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6o6n.png)

[My connection string in xamarin.forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy96D.png)

Comment: Did you try to ask this question on Super User forum? This doesn't look like programming question; and therefore, doesn't meet SO guidelines. I would try to set up a client (like, PhpMysqlAdmin) outside your home network, and ensure that it works before testing from the phone

Comment: Hi @Felix thanks, I have posted this same question to Super User Forum.